# quickfix sends logout in response to logon

Tags: quickfix

I have a FIX server and client implemented using quickfix v1.14.3. When the client sends a logon request, the server immediately sends a logout message.There is nothing in the logs to indicate why it is so. The SenderCompID and TargetCompID both match between the server and client. I have removed the previous sessions states on both the server and client. Is there any way to find why the server is sending the logout message?
Here is the server configuration

```
enter code here
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=acceptor
ReconnectInterval=60
FileStorePath=/temp/quickfix/mktdata
SocketAcceptPort=32323
SocketReuseAddress=Y
SenderCompID=Server1
[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=INCA
StartTime=00:30:00
EndTime=21:30:00
ReconnectInterval=30
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=6523
SocketConnectHost=0.0.0.0
DataDictionary=/opt/quickfix/spec/FIX44.xml
```

Here is the client configuration

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=1
FileStorePath=/temp/quickfix/order
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
SocketConnectHost=localhost
UseDataDictionary=Y
SenderCompID=INCA
DataDictionary=/opt/quickfix/spec/FIX44.xml
[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=Server1
SocketConnectPort=32323
```

Comment: There's *nothing* in your Acceptor's event or message logs?  Really?

Comment: No. The event log has entry saying Created session. Then another entry  Disconnecting. The message log shows the incoming logon message(35=A) and the outgoing logout message(35=5).

Comment: I think it may be due to starttime/endtime. My problems occurred in the evening when the time is past the endtime(UTC).

Comment: Ah, of course.  That makes sense.  Your Initiator was trying to connect to an off-duty Acceptor.  I should have noticed that.

Comment: You should answer your own question and then accept it when StackOverflow lets you.

Comment: Just put the answer in as a CWiki, if Ram comes back I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

Answering from the comments, it's a start time/end time issue.

> I think it may be due to StartTime/EndTime. My problems occurred in the evening when the time is past the EndTime(UTC).–  RamJul 27 at 13:13

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like problem of not matching StartTime and EndTime settings of the Acceptor and the Initiator. However, if you like find out more, implement IApplicationExt instead of IApplication, and in the section where you override the IApplication interface functions, override also FromEarlyIntercept and test msg for "is Logout":

```
public void FromEarlyIntercept(Message msg, SessionID sessionID)
    {
        string msgText = msg.GetField(Tags.Text);
        if (msg is Logout)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Connection of Session {0} forced to logout, because: {1}", sessionID, msgText);
        }
```

There in the respective Logout tags content you may find the explanation for your LogOut. I hope this helps.